# sliding window over 2d array in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, arrays, 2d, multidimensional-array

I'm having problems with sliding a variable sized window over a 2D array in vb.net. my porblem is when I take the first element of the array at 0,0 what ever the size of the window is it needs to be smaller because the element in question has to be the center of the sliding window. ex: arrar size(40,43) window size 5x5 ( window size is NxN N=3 wins size is 3x3) so array(0,0) with win size 5 so 2 col and 2 rows need to be cout out and a new window size of 3x3. any help would be great.`

```
Public Function getPIXELSinWINDOW(ByVal Wsize As Integer, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer)

        Dim tempARRAY As New ArrayList()
        Dim Xwidth As Integer = Wsize
        Dim Yheight As Integer = Wsize
        Dim Xvalue As Integer = x - Wsize / 2
        Dim Yvalue As Integer = y - Wsize / 2
        Dim imgHEIGHT As Integer = Me.mysize.Height
        Dim imgWIDTH As Integer = Me.mysize.Width
        Dim i, j As Integer


        While Xvalue < 0
            Xvalue += 1
            Xwidth -= 1
        End While
        While Xvalue > imgWIDTH
            Xvalue -= 1
            Xwidth -= 1
        End While
        While Xwidth >= imgWIDTH
            Xwidth -= 1
        End While
        While Xvalue + Xwidth > imgWIDTH
            Xwidth -= 1
        End While

        While Yvalue < 0
            Yvalue += 1
            Yheight -= 1
        End While
        While Yvalue > imgHEIGHT
            Yvalue -= 1
            Yheight -= 1
        End While
        While Yheight >= imgHEIGHT
            Yheight -= 1
        End While
        While Yvalue + Yheight > imgHEIGHT
            Yheight -= 1
        End While

        For i = Xvalue To Xvalue + Xwidth
            For j = Yvalue To Yvalue + Yheight
                tempARRAY.Add(pixels(j, i))
            Next
        Next

        Return tempARRAY
    End Function
```

the var pixels is the 2d array

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        MainClass mc = new MainClass();
        List<int> pix = mc.GetPixelsInWindow(5, 40, 43);            
    }

    private int[,] data = new int[40, 43];

    public List<int> GetPixelsInWindow(int windowSize, int xPoint, int yPoint)
    {
        // As we are dealing with integers, this will result in a truncated value,
        // so a windowSize of 5 will yield a windowDelta of 2.
        int windowDelta = windowSize / 2;
        List<int> pixels = new List<int>();

        int xMin = Math.Max(0, xPoint - windowDelta);
        int xMax = Math.Min(data.GetLength(0) - 1, xPoint + windowDelta);

        int yMin = Math.Max(0, yPoint - windowDelta);
        int yMax = Math.Min(data.GetLength(1) - 1, yPoint + windowDelta);

        for (int x = xMin; x <= xMax; x++)
        {
            for (int y = yMin; y <= yMax; y++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Getting pixel (" + x.ToString() + ", " + y.ToString() + ")...");
                pixels.Add(data[x, y]);
            }
        }   

        return pixels;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, and sorry for the example being in C#, but I hope you can understand it anyway! :)

Comment: im not sure im reading this right but what if im at 20,10 in the data array will this give me the full window of 25 values?

Comment: Yes it will. You can create a console project, paste this class and run it as the main class. This way you can play with different values to make sure it works as intended. Also, I can add a version with more code comments, if you like.